# How to display first 3 letters in a word, but replace the remainder of the word with "-" dashes in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, str-replace

Lets say I have a word, and I only want to display the first three letters of the word. But the remaining last letters need to show a dash or an asterisk, etc.

For example, if we have the word `javascript`, then the output should display `jav-------`, `pebbles` should display as `peb----`, or instead of `python`, the output should display `pyt---`, etc.

Would `str.replace(old, new)` or `str.replace(old, new, count)` work in this case? If yes, then how?

Here is an example I did:

```
>>> p = "kotlin"

>>> p = p.replace(p[3:], "-")

>>> p

'kot-'
>>>
```

The desired output would display `kot---`, however, although it does show the first 3 letters in the word, `kot-` only shows one dash in the end.

What could be another way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string multiplication:

```py
dashes = "-" * len(p[3:])
p = p[:3] + dashes
```

Comment: This answer is great! However, if we use the word "Java", and I utilize what you stated, it outputs 'j-v-' instead of 'jav-'; why would this occur?

Comment: That's because the string after the third position only consists of an `"a"`. And a single `"a"` also exists elsewhere in the string, and `.replace(x, y)` replaces all instances of `x` with `y`. That means that both of the `"a"`s were replaced -> `"java".replace("a", "-")`. I'll edit my answer to account for that ^

Comment: Ahh, I see now. That would explain why both a's were in dashes. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. Great response :)

Answer (score 3):

You could make a for loop or even use len(p) to check how many letters are there, subtract 3 and then place the number of words after the first 3,

```
p = "kotlin"
p[:3]+"-"*(len(p)-3)
```

output

```
"kot---"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def display_dashes(string):
    dashed_string = "-"*len(string)
    return string[:3]+dashed_string[:len(dashed_string)-3]
display_dashes("kotlin")
#'kot---'
```

Or You can use [str.ljust()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/ljust.html) function to solve this one line

```
display_dashes = lambda string :string[:3].ljust(len(string),'-')
display_dashes("kotlin")
#'kot---'
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
p = "kotlin"
x = 3
p[:x]+'-'*x
```

Output

```
'kot---'
```